# How can I pass the MongoDb collection name from property files to java code?

Tags: java, database, mongodb

I have the Java Code where I want to pass the collection name of mongodb from property file or I don't want to hardcode it in Java . This is what I have already tried but seems it is not working.

I have a **POJO** as :

```
@Document(collection = "${@DatabaseRepositoryCustom.getCollectionName()}")
public class A{}
```

I have **one interface** as :

```
@Repository
public interface Repo extends MongoRepository<A, String> ,DatabaseRepositoryCustom {
}
```

I have **second interface** as :

```
public interface DatabaseRepositoryCustom {
    String getCollectionName();
    void setCollectionName(String collectionName);
}
```

I have a **implementation class** of second interface as :

```
public class DatabaseRepositoryCustomImpl implements DatabaseRepositoryCustom  {

    private static String collectionName = "Emp";
    @Override
    public String getCollectionName() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setCollectionName(String collectionName) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.collectionName = collectionName;

    }
}
```

I have a **controller class** which is again setting the collection name(just to check) :

```
public class Controller {
    @Autowired
    private Repo rp;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws IOException {
        rp.setCollectionName("Emp1");

    }
}
```

So I was thinking and asking if I can use this approach to pass the Mongo collection name using property file ? 
If yes , then how do I achieve it because with this approach I am not able to get the collection name and I am getting the error as :

> caused by: org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Query failed with error code 73 and error message 'Invalid collection name specified ' db_name.${@DatabaseRepositoryCustom.getCollectionName()}'

If no , then how would I pass it using property files ?